# How to count the frequency of each string in the already sorted ArrayList without using Stream API, MAP, Hashset, collection API

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist, frequency

I have tried using below code, though it works but does not satisfy the requirement.Please share your knowledge , Thanks

```
String temp;                                
for(int i = 0; i < lexicon.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = lexicon.size() - 1; j > i; j--)
    {
        if (lexicon.get(i).compareTo(lexicon.get(j)) > 0)
        {
            temp  = lexicon.get(i);
            lexicon.set(i,lexicon.get(j)) ;
            lexicon.set(j,temp);
        }
    }
}


ArrayList<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < lexicon.size(); i++)       //Removing duplicates 
{
    int wordCount = 1;
    uniqueWords.add(lexicon.get(i));
    for(int j = i+1; j < lexicon.size(); j++)
    {
        if(uniqueWords.get(i).equals(lexicon.get(j)))
        {
            wordCount++;
            lexicon.remove(j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(uniqueWords.get(i) + "  " + wordCount);
}
```

This is the output i am getting:

```
a  6
a  3
a  2
about  1
acknowledged  1
all  1
also  1
and  2
answer  1
at  2
austen  1
be  2
been  1
bennet  2
bennet  1
```

I need something like this:  Word  Count for that word

```
a 11
about 1
acknowledge 1
```

and so on

Comment: *without using Stream API* Do it like you would with stream API and then replace it with `for` loop or use iterator.

Comment: I think we need a bit more information. What is `lexicon`, why is your `uniqueWords` is a `List` and not a `Set`? Also provide an example input with the expected output please!

Comment: lexicon- take it as any other variable name:

Comment: i do not want to use any subset of collection api

Comment: Man I know lexicon is a variable... What is it's type? What's the initial value? The code you provided is not full.

Comment: it is an unsorted arraylist which has some random words at each index
example: 0 pride, 1 and 2, prejudice and so on

Comment: does not seem to be giving error on my screen.
What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry the error was my fault when I tried t reproduce your code (cuz you didn't give me the full code)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are removing elements from your lexicon at `lexicon.remove(j);` and also moving forward in your lexicon with your check at `lexicon.get(j)`

I don't want to give you the full code that works, because you won't learn anything from that, but I hope I gave you enough hint, to solve your problem. Try debugging your code, and see what happens with the variables :)

Answer (score 0):

On removal at index `j`, `j` get's increased by j++, actually *skipping* one, where it should have continued without increasing.

As already sorted:

```
String word = uniqueWords.get(i);
int j = i+1;
while (j < lexicon.size() && word.equals(lexicon.get(j)))
{
    wordCount++;
    lexicon.remove(j);
}
```

(I'll give the code, as it shows a somewhat different approach.)

Comment: @aBnormaLz I normally refrain from giving code, so I understand. But I would not like him to keep using ++j, introducing --j in the if. maybe a break, and would prefer him to learn _clean_ code. I would have felt that a mention of `break` would make sense.

Comment: lexicon.remove(j) - its job is to remove the duplicate ones,nothing else
This code works completely fine if the lexicon is unsorted.
Since it is sorted,causing problems

Comment: @aBnormaLz Please stop judging 
you do not know who is senior, junior , beginner

Comment: @jatinmittal still aBnormaLz does have a point: the problem should still remain interesting, some effort needed. He got a +1 from me. My answer relies on the array being sorted. Exploiting that would mean a loop removing i+1's. And such a bit different approach is best explained with code.

Comment: By the way aBnormaL.z though not doing many answers is sufficiently senior, just his manga avatar...

Comment: So now you are judging me by my avatar? :D also there is 99% chance, that the OP is a junior, cuz if you are familiar a bit with any IDE or any language, you should be able debug this problem :) Also i think you shouldn't learn clean code at the beginning. First you should get familiar with the environment, the mindset, and other stuff. After when you can solve a problem in several different ways, and you can choose between the good and the better, then you can learn stuff like clean code.

Comment: Peace ;), now let's get back to work, bonan tagon, jó napot, शुभ दिवस.